# How to get Input text values by using Collection <Part>

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have several `input type="text"` with the same name.

`<input type="text" name="fieldname">`

`<input type="text" name="fieldname">`

`<input type="text" name="fieldname">`

Im trying to get the values inside those text fields.
They are in a form used to upload images,  that's why im using `Collection <Part>`

Inside this loops, how can i get the values of those text fields? I missed a part of code

```
 for (Part part: mhyCollectionParts) {           
             String filename = mhyCollectionParts.getName();             
             if(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("fieldname")){
                 //then...??????                     
             }               
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Servlet 3.0 then you should be able to use
`String fieldnameValues = request.getParameterValues("fieldname");` you don't need to use to [`Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) to get values of your form field, but if you are using servlet < 3.0 you need to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/1484017). `<web-app ... version="xxx">` tag in your **web.xml** will give you details of servlet api you are using.